# How to read an excel file from local disk into plsql?

Tags: excel, csv, plsql, xlsx, utl-file

Is it possible to read an xlsx or csv file from local disk and display its contents in plsql?

I have been seeing examples of UTL_FILE to do the same, but it looks like it is only for files located on the server. I'm working on a Windows machine.

Comment: UTL_FILE *only* reads from local disk - files located on the server *are* local as far as the database is concerned :) Perhaps you mean files on a client machine? In that case, the answer is no - you need to set up some kind of means to have the files transported to the server first before they can be read by the database.

Comment: I'm not well versed with UTL_FILE . Could you please help me out with the syntax?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS069

Comment: Y U no read documentation? but do you mean that you have file on your machine and you want to upload it to server? this is not pl/sql question this is infrastructure question then and you should ask DB administrator.

Comment: I have already read the documentation and it didn't seem to be of much help.
The documentation uses a line UTL_FILE.FOPEN('user_dir','u12345.tmp','R',256) , but never mentions what the fields stand for.
 I am not trying to upload a file to the server, and if I was, I would have mentioned the same in the question.
I was simply trying to read a file from the local desktop into a plsql procedure and display its contents.